# Chat client where System.windows.forms namespace does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I'm writing a chat client on asp.net and would like to use System.windows.forms namespace which does not exist.

I know you can't use the system.windows.forms namespace in asp.net but how can I then use this code to write a chat client in asp.net.

```
private void GChat_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
{


        tbxStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {


            if ((e.MessageString) == tbxName.Text + " said: " + tbxMessage.Text + "")
            {
                tbxStatus.Text += "You said: " + tbxMessage.Text + "\r\n";
                tbxMessage.Clear();
                tbxStatus.SelectionStart = tbxStatus.Text.Length;
                tbxStatus.ScrollToCaret();

                if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Bat Signal Activated", "You Have New Messages", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tbxStatus.Text += e.MessageString.Remove(e.MessageString.Length -1) + "\r\n";

                if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                     this.Hide();
                     notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Bat Signal Activated", "You Have New Messages", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                }
            }
 });
 }
 }
```